# Running single TestNG test with dependency in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng

I have few tests in a class that are dependent on setup group from another package.
My TestNG.xml looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="mysuite" verbose="1">
<test name="mytest">
    <classes>
    <class name="path.to.setup.class"/>
    <class name="path.to.test.class"/>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

This is working fine when running all tests in eclipse.

the problem is when I try to execute a single test from testClass, that is dependent on setup group.
I get the following error: DependencyMap::Method "myMethod" depends on nonexistent group "setup".
Is there any easy way to execute a single test without creating a separate xml for each test?

Comment: what about a second "setup" group in the same class as your tests which you copy & paste wherever you need it and remove afterwards?

Comment: Obviously this will work, but it makes test debugging somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: Another chance you have is, to make an AbstractTest class with all the "setup" methods in it and subclass it with your test classes. That's what I do. btw- for setup matters you can use @Before* annotations.

Comment: I'm using a different class, as the setup is common all classes. I don't use the @Before* annotations as some of the tests are not dependent on it and I don't want them to fail in case the setup fails.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opinion is to have an abstract superclass of the testclasses which does all the setup stuff. That can be achieved within the superclass' standard constructor or (better imo) by adding @Before* annotated methods. With the @Before* and @After* methods you have the freedom of choice which method should run related to testng groups, depending on other methods, error/exception handling or tear down.
If you have class specific setup stuff you can do it in an @Before* method in the class itself relying on the execution of the superior setup.

Comment: Ill add some samples later